# Hacer que ciclo while se corte en 8

Tags: python

Mi contador no se detiene en `8` y no estoy entendiendo por que, si me pueden dar una mano, me ayudarían mucho.

```py
def entregaCupos():

    global cupos
    contador=1
    patente= str(input("ingrese la patente del camion"))
    while (contador > 0) and (contador <= 8):
        if (cupos[0] == 0):
            cupos=[patente]
            estado=["P"]
        else:
            if patente in cupos:
                print ("la patente ingresada ya tiene un cupo")
            else:
                estado += ['P']
                cupos += [patente]
        print(f"{cupos}\n{estado}")
        patente = str(input("ingrese la patente del camion"))
    if (contador >= 9):
        print("se alcanzo el maximo de cupos")
    return cupos
```

Comment: Un problema es que `contador=1`, pero en ninguna parte se incrementa. Eso se podría arreglar colocando un `contador += 1` en alguna parte del código. Pero hay más errores `if (cupos[0] == 0)` da error si cupos está vacío. ¿Qué valores (y cómo) debe tener la variable `cupos` al finalizar el programa?

Comment: no se si en Python es asi pero no deberias incrementar el contador? algo como contador++;. ? el contador ahi siempre es 1

Comment: @aeportugal En python no se puede realizar ese tipo de incrementos, debes ´contador+=1;´. IgnacioBastianelli Para hacerlo más simple puedes usar un bucle ´for´: ´for contador in range(8): #You codes´

Comment: @DanielBriceño ¿Un ciclo `for` para incrementar una simple variable? Nah, `contador += 1` está bien. Hay casos en los que un `while` sirve mejor que un `for`. ¿Qué pasa si una de las entradas del usuario no cumple?, la lista quedará con un elemento menos y si se equivoca otra vez, ahora serán 2 elementos menos, y así...

Comment: @aeportugal Este problema en otro lenguajes de programación como C/C++ se resolvería fácilmente con disminuir la variable contador, pero en python como lo que hace el bucle for es solo recorrer un rango determinado por la función range y solo le agrega el indice actual al la variable(en este caso ´contador=indice actual´) En otra palabra el bucle for no depende de la variable contador. para llegar al rango marcado, por lo que tu tienes razón en este caso.

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego En python no se puede realizar ese tipo de incrementos, debes ´contador+=1;´. aeportugal Me equivoque de persona   : )

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente falto aumentar el valor que contiene la variable contador, dentro de tu ciclo while. debido a que contador no es modificado, se mantiene 0 a lo largo de las iteraciones y se ejecuta el ciclo while infinitamente.

la correcion consiste en agregar un contador += 1 dentro del while

```
def entregaCupos():
    global cupos
    contador=1
    patente= str(input("ingrese la patente del camion"))
    while (contador > 0) and (contador <= 8):
        if (cupos[0] == 0):
            cupos=[patente]
            estado=["P"]
        else:
            if patente in cupos:
                print ("la patente ingresada ya tiene un cupo")
            else:
                estado += ['P']
                cupos += [patente]

        contador += 1
        print(f"{cupos}\n{estado}")
        patente = str(input("ingrese la patente del camion"))

    if (contador >= 9):
        print("se alcanzo el maximo de cupos")
    return cupos
```